# get text from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Хочу получить текст из description, чтобы потом передать его в другую активность. Записываю этот текст в descrp. Для тестирования вывожу значение этой переменной в TextView, получаю пустоту ( хотя в ввожу символы). C переменной title все работает отлично. Что не так с descrp ?

```
 editTextDiscr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
 final String descrp = editTextDiscr.getText().toString();
 final String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("Title");
 nameofplant.setText(title);
 nameofplant.setText(descrp);
```

Comment: Вы этот код в `onCreate` пишете? Тогда логично, что `EditText` при записи переменной ещё пуст. Берите текст после ввода, например в обработчике кнопки перехода в другую активность.

Comment: скиньте полный код

Comment: @woesss Да спасибо, именно в этом проблема была.Поместил в обработчик кнопки и все заработало)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было действительно как сказал @woesss записывать информацию из edittext после метода OnCreate, так как на этом этапе edittext пуст. Сделал следующим образом:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addition);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbaredit);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    editTextDiscr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
    final String[] descrp = new String[1];
     @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            descrp[0] = editTextDiscr.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Addition.this, MyPlants.class);

            intent.putExtra("Description", descrp[0]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
   };
```

Comment: Я бы ещё проверку на пустоту добавил ибо юзер в кнопку ткнул, а текст вводить поленился)))